# Android Studio Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. >

Tags: android

I am having issues with my capstone project and have looked around online but my issue will not go away. I have tried closing and reopening android studio, changing the build type of my project and have come up short on getting the error resolved I'm attaching a picture of the error at run time. Hopefully someone can help me resolve this issue.
[android error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSHlY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your permission:

```
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`"
```

There is no need for the back tick **`**

Comment: Thank You!!!!! i cant believe it was that simple I got ahead of myself before when trying to add GoogleMapsAPI into the app!